# Why I generated wrong Taylor series?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I want to prove the expression `Limit[Sin[x*x] *Exp[-x*x]*x, x -> Infinity] ==0`
So I do this `Normal[  Series[ Sin[x*x] *Exp[-x*x]*x, {x, 0, 40}]]`.And the result 
imply the expression will be infinity.

That is odd, and I make some change. Let `t=x^2`, then the expression will be `Limit[Sin[t] *Exp[-t]*Sqrt[t], t -> Infinity]`. I try again `Normal[  Series[Sin[x] *Exp[-x]*Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 40}]]`. That's the answer I need. 
[The right series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3ZoD.png)

I can't figure out what's wrong. Why I can't generate series directly?

I wnat to say thay f, f1 and f2 should be the same, but they looks like this:
[f=f1,but f2 diffuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpHVH.png)

Comment: Why do you want to prove it by using Mathematica? The term obviously has its infimum at zero... If f(x) = g(x) * h(x), then lim(f(x)) = lim(g(x)) * lim(h(x)). g(x) = sin(x^2) and h(x) = exp(-x^2))*x. g(x) in [-1, 1] and lim(h(x)) = 0 for x-> inf...

Comment: @SvenKrüger of course you are right. But I find that most problems can be solved by taylor series expect this. When I do some change, it still works. That really confused me.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. What is "the answer [you] need"? Is the series representation of f(x) wrong in comparison to f (t) = sin(t) * exp(t) * sqrt(t)? You should be aware that a finite Taylor series is just an approximation and your symbolic computing system is only operating on coefficients and exponents with floating point precision or fractions in most cases, which also produces some rounding error.

Comment: @SvenKrüger yeah. I said the last one is right because its error is closing to zero. But the first one won’t, I get a very large number.

Comment: Please edit your question and point out what is the actual input you get a "wrong" output for and share them both. You show four different lines of input. I do not see which of them leads to "wrong" output.

Comment: But f1 still diffuse.

Answer (score 1):

`Normal[Series[Sin[x*x]*Exp[-x*x]*x, {x, 0, 40}]]`

with `t = x^2` is equivalent to

`Normal[Series[Sin[t]*Exp[-t]*x, {x, 0, 40}]]`

because `x != Sqrt[x^2]` e.g. for `x = -2

Results for negative `t` are not plotted.

`Plot[Sin[t]*Exp[-t]*Sqrt[t], {t, -8, 8}]`

[image]